# Ispost back like functionality in WPF pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a WPF application which contains a large number of pages. I want to know whether there is any function which is similar to IsPostBack in Asp.Net. I just wanted to know is this the first time the specific page is loading. Thanks in advance.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Custom_Track_Reports.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="LoginWindow" >
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
<Grid Background="#FF58B0DF" Height="401">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF0F3F4" Height="173" Margin="45,197,58,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" />
        <Image Height="125" Margin="340,10,330,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Images/logo_lrg.png"/>
        <Label Content="Custom Track Reports" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.607,1.112" Width="268" Height="47" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="26" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox Margin="128,0,0,110" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="25" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="21" Text="" Name="userTextBox" FontStretch="Expanded" Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="546" AcceptsReturn="False" KeyDown="userTextBox_KeyDown" />
        <Button x:Name="enterButton" Content="Enter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,311,166,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="26" FontSize="14" Style="{DynamicResource button}" Click="enterButton_Click"/>
        <Label Content="User ID" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,215,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: There is no postback for windows forms... Actually there is also no postback for web. But Microsoft wanted to attract windows forms devs to asp.net, they tried to provide windows forms like developmenet experience so we can have Button.Click event IsPostBack is side effect of this abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If your page navigation is taking place via `Frame`, then attach to the `Frame.Navigated` event. If you provide more detail (some XAML and code) then we might be able to be more helpful...